# Cyrillic is not displayed at Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I did this:

```
public class FilterInit implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceRequestEncoding(true);
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic endcodingFilter = servletContext.addFilter("endcodingFilter", characterEncodingFilter);
        endcodingFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
    }
}
```

But still got this:

[image: screenshot]

The situation is even worse for validated forms, like this one:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find many solutions to this problem in Google(mostly by adding StringHttpMessageConverter or CharacterEncodingFilter). But everything I'd try didn't help. But I found the solution — setting character encoding for ViewResolver!

```
 resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```